# How can I hide swagger ui endpoints from servicestack metadata?

Tags: servicestack

The ServiceStack.Api.Swagger defines 2 endpoints

- Resources and
- ResourceRequest

These are used by swagger-ui in order to display rest documentation. How can I hide them from showing up in the standard metadata page of servicestack? I cannot decorate them with the [Restrict] attribute because they are defined internally within the ServiceStack.Api.Swagger dll.

Regards

Dirk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new v4 feature of adding [.NET Attributes at runtime](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#add-code-first-attributes-at-runtime-de-coupled-from-pocos) to control the visibility of services you don't control with ServiceStack's built-in [Restriction attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Restricting-Services), e.g. to only allow the attributes to be visible for localhost you can add restriction attributes to the specific Request DTO's in your AppHost:

```
typeof(Resources)
  .AddAttributes(new RestrictAttribute { VisibleLocalhostOnly = true });
typeof(ResourceRequest)
  .AddAttributes(new RestrictAttribute { VisibleLocalhostOnly = true });
```

To hide it for all requests you can set the visibility to none:

```
typeof(Resources)
  .AddAttributes(new RestrictAttribute { VisibilityTo=RequestAttributes.None });
typeof(ResourceRequest)
  .AddAttributes(new RestrictAttribute { VisibilityTo=RequestAttributes.None });
```

Note they'll still be shown in development mode when `Debug=true` which is automatically enabled for **Debug** builds, to simulate a release build you can set it to false, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    DebugMode = false
});
```

Comment: Awesome! V4 rocks! Thank You!